# MongoDB - geo location search with subdocument index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, geospatial

Consider the following use case: we have a collection of companies, each company has multiple offices. And then, an office has a location:

```
[
    {
        "name": "stackoverflow",
        "offices": [
             {"offname": "so_l1", "location": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [X + 1, Y + 1]}},
             {"offname": "so_l2", "location": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [X + 2, Y + 2]}}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "quora",
        "offices": [
             {"offname": "q_l1", "location": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [X + 3, Y + 3]}},
             {"offname": "q_l2", "location": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [X + 666, Y + 666]}}
        ]
    }
]

createIndex({offices.location. '2dsphere'})
```

Let `X, Y` be some geo coordinates. Now, I want to find exactly 3 offices closest to `(X, Y)`. I also want them to be in a flat structure. The final result should contain `[so_l1, so_l2, q_l1]`.

So I wanted to try aggregation pipeline, with `$geoNear` followed by `$unwind`.

However, when I try to execute the first step of the pipeline:

```
"$geoNear": {
    "near": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [X, Y]},
    "distanceField": "distance",
    "includeLocs": "resLocation",
    "spherical": true
    // what about limit? if i put it here, it will be applied at the document level
}
```

it will return exactly 2 results, ordered by distance ascending, being the lowest distance among all office subdocuments (same for includeLocs field).

**Is there a way to find more than 1 office by geospatial index? Or to duplicate the outer collection entries (companies) so that I can easily unwind the entries in the next step?**

Is there any other way of solving this specific use case than **creating flattened collection of Offices and then using geospatial index to find top level documents?**